# How do I replace a part of a variable with another variable

Tags: java, variables

I'm attempting to not use tons of IF statements here. 
I have 26 different boxes named txtA, txtB, txtC etc.

What i'm trying to create is a method where the variable "box" can be used giving

```
String result = txt(box).getText();
```

Where box would be substituted in for any letter.

Thankyou, here is my code

```
public static String getTextBoxInput(char box) {        
    String result = txtA.getText();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You want an array.

Comment: or an `ArrayList<JTextField>` or a Map such as a HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Build a `Map<String, TextBox>()` containing your text boxes, with your letter as a key and use it this way:

```
public static String getTextBoxInput(char box) {
    TextBox textBox = textBoxMap.get(box);

    if (textBox != null)    {
        return textBoxMap.get(box).getText();
    }

    return null;
}
```

With your map being:

```
"A", txtA
"B", txtB
```

And so on. This is your simplest option, either for adding another box or finding them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

An array can be used here. I hope this helps.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Task {
    static BOX Box[] = new BOX[26];
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    /*assuming that the variable box can only get input as an English uppercase
      alphabet and characters stored in box can range from A to Z.
    */
    public static String getTextBoxInput(char box) {
        String result = Box[box - 65].getText(); //ASCII value of 'A' is 65
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initializing the elements of BOX with their respective Strings
        for(int i = 0; i < 26 ; i++)
            Box[i] = new BOX( "Sample_String "+(i+1) );

        char box = in.next().charAt(0);
        String result = getTextBoxInput(box);

        System.out.print("RESULT : "+result);
    }
}

class BOX {
    String text;
    public BOX(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```